# keep only `Groups` where at least 2 element in a column are present within a list in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a list such as :

```
The_list=c('SP1','SP2','SP3')
```

And I have a dataframe such as

```
Names Groups 
SP1   G1
SP2   G1
SP3   G1
SP1   G2
SP4   G3
SP5   G4
SP2   G5
SP3   G5
SP6   G5 
SP2   G6
SP7   G6
```

And I would like to keep only `Groups` where at least 2 element in `Names` are present within `The_list`;

Here I should get:

```
Names Groups 
SP1   G1
SP2   G1
SP3   G1
SP2   G5
SP3   G5
SP6   G5
```

Here is the df if it can helps

```
structure(list(Names = c("SP1", "SP2", "SP3", "SP1", "SP4", "SP5", 
"SP2", "SP3", "SP6", "SP2", "SP7"), Groups = c("G1", "G1", "G1", 
"G2", "G3", "G4", "G5", "G5", "G5", "G6", "G6")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution you can use is

```
df |> 
  group_by(Groups) |> 
  filter(sum(Names %in% The_list) >= 2)
```

Correction... because I'm using Names %in% The_list
it does not uniquely identify each Name, which may cause some groups
to be displayed because duplicate names.

```
df |> 
  group_by(Groups) |> 
  filter(sum(The_list %in% Names) >= 2)
```

```
  Names Groups
  <chr> <chr> 
1 SP1   G1    
2 SP2   G1    
3 SP3   G1    
4 SP2   G5    
5 SP3   G5    
6 SP6   G5
```

Comment: Depending on the duplicates in 'Names' per Groups, I was thinking `The_list %in% Names` or `unique(Names) %in% The_list`

Comment: Youre absolutely correct. I'll leave my original answer up for others to see the error

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df1[, .I[sum(The_list %in% Names) >=2], by = Groups]$V1]
```

-output

```
    Names Groups
   <char> <char>
1:    SP1     G1
2:    SP2     G1
3:    SP3     G1
4:    SP2     G5
5:    SP3     G5
6:    SP6     G5
```